# Serialization of Unordered Map Using Fstream

Tags: c++, file, serialization, file-io, io

I need to serialize an unordered map. The method below uses `fstream` to read and write data into the map in binary mode. However, it prints `0` instead of `5` after clearing the map and loading it back in. These functions work correctly when modified to be used with a `vector` instead of an `unordered_map`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void saveData(unordered_map<int, int>* p_map_ptr) {
    fstream file("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

    file.seekp(0);
    file.write((char*) p_map_ptr, sizeof(*p_map_ptr));
    file.close();
}

void loadData(unordered_map<int, int>* p_map_ptr) {
    fstream file("data.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

    file.seekg(0);
    file.read((char*) p_map_ptr, sizeof(*p_map_ptr));
    file.close();
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, int> map;

    map[0] = 5;
    saveData(&map);
    map.clear();
    loadData(&map);

    cout << map[0];
}
```

Comment: You are actually serializing the binary representation of the map object itself. First, this is undefined behavior; second, this cannot work. You need to serialize the content of the map — its elements. If you do not want to do this manually by yourself, use some serialization library (IIRC, Boost.Serialization should be able to serialize standard library containers).

Comment: simply writing the binary representation of some object to a file is strictly speaking no serialization. Serialization is the act of writing an object in a form that allows to restore the object later. When the object contains pointers (and a `unordered_map` certainly does) you cannot store the adress of a pointer and later restore the state of the object from that adress in a meaningful way

Comment: If you want to write your own serialization of data then read the FAQ https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization as it is very far from trivial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containers serialization is a trivial problem, for `unordered_map` it's implemented as a hashtable, its implementation is somewhat complex, you may get a glance from this [picture](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-215f515d861129fa01d5068e95b11878).

In your code, you are expected that the `unordered_map` have a beginning address `(char*) p_map_ptr` and a fixed size `sizeof(*p_map_ptr)` and with continuous memory layout, it's wrong.

The begin address `(char*) p_map_ptr` is the `unordered_map`'s address, it may contain a bucket vector's address, and have nothing to do with the elements' address, the elements are stored in the list with are stored in the buckets.

The size `sizeof(*p_map_ptr)` is just the `unordered_map`'s size, not all the element's size, if we change it to `p_map_ptr->sizes() * sizeof(decltype(p_map_ptr)::value_type)` it would  get all the element's total size, but we still can't use this size to copy memory. Since the memory layout of `std::unrodered_map` is dispersed.

A considerable choice is to use [boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html):

```cpp
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void saveData(const unordered_map<int, int>& map,
              const std::string& file = "data.bin") {
  std::ofstream filestream(file);
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(filestream,
                                          boost::archive::no_codecvt);

  archive << map;
}

void loadData(unordered_map<int, int>* p_map_ptr,
              const std::string& file = "data.bin") {
  std::ifstream filestream(file);
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(filestream,
                                          boost::archive::no_codecvt);

  archive >> *p_map_ptr;
}

int main() {
  unordered_map<int, int> map;

  map[0] = 5;
  map[1] = 6;
  saveData(map);
  map.clear();
  loadData(&map);

  cout << map[0];
}
```

To build the code, we need to add a linkage flag, for Linux: `-lboost_serialization`

Related answer: To serialize and deserialize with [text archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31731908/1292791), it's more human-readable but less performant than binary archive here.